# How to change search parameters based on value of checkbox in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm an MVC noob so bear with me, I'm used to working with web forms.  I have a page where administrators can view all users.  Right now it shows ALL users, inactive and active.  I can make it show only active users by default, but I would like to have a checkbox that can be clicked in order to show inactive users.  I want the change to occur as soon as the box is checked or unchecked.

In the view:

```
@Html.CheckBox("ShowInactive")  <label for="inactvCheckBox">Show Inactive Users</label>
```

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(bool ShowInactive)
{

    var users = (ShowInactive) ? db.Users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName) :
        db.Users.Where(u => u.Active == 1).OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
    return View(users.ToList());
}
```

Obviously the way I'm doing it doesn't work, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Index isn't receiving the value of ShowInactive and I get a null parameter entry error.

EDIT: apparently I need some javascript to handle the click event, and then pass the checkbox state to the controller; I guess I thought it would automatically link with the parameter name being the same.  I tried adding the following javascript below, but it doesn't work. Again, I've probably written it wrong but my Google-fu is failing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ShowInactive').change(function () {
                $("form").attr("Index", "/User/Index");
                $("form").submit();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: how is this ActionResult getting kicked off? is there missing javascript that you haven't included?

Comment: Your checkbox is named differently from your parameter, and you will need javascript to submit the form when you click on it.

Comment: Ah just noticed the parameter name. They were originally the same when I first tested it, I changed it in the controller to try something different, then forgot to change it back when I pasted it here. There's no JavaScript in the view, as index executes on page load. How should I best handle the form submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.  I didn't actually need to handle anything through the controller, I just loaded *all* users to the list and then added a hidden class to users who weren't active.  Then upon checkbox click I toggled the hidden rows using javascript. It's quicker than reloading the view every time I click the checkbox.  Only problem is it messes up alternating row colors when inactive users are hidden, but this page is only looked at by site admins so no big deal.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = db.Users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
    return View(users.ToList());
}
```

View:

```
@Html.CheckBox("ShowInactive", false, new { id = "ShowInactive" }) <label>Show Inactive Users</label> 

[...]

@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(u => u.LastName).ThenBy(u => u.FirstName))
{
   <tr @if(item.Active != 1) { <text>class="inactive hidden"</text>}>
   [row data stuff]
   </tr>
}
```

Javascript in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ShowInactive').change(function () {
            $(".inactive").toggleClass("hidden");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the checkbox to:

```
@Html.CheckBox("ShowInactv")
```

Thereby matching the parameter of your Action.